# Fundamental group of the following figure: (half-full sphere with two "quotiented" holes)

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

Let $X$ be the following figure:

[image]

> I want to find the fundamental groups $\pi_{1}(X)$ and $\pi_{1}(X/\beta)$ (up to isomorphism), determine whether $B$, the part of the image including the "$\beta$-circle" and below, is a retract of $X$, and determine whether the equator cirlce (the "filling" of the circle contains the equator) is a retract of $X$.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get too far on my own, but here's everything I got: first, $X$ is homotopic to a sphere with a "filled-in" equator, because we can contract the "filling" into a single disc. Then, we can contract that disc into a point, and get the wedge sum of two spheres, of which one has a disc-shaped hole with the $\alpha$ identification, and the other one has a circle with a triple $\beta$ identification. I've included a picture in case my explanation isn't clear: [image]

I know the upper sphere of the wedge sum is the real projective plane, whose fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$; however, I can't find the other one. $\pi_{1}(X)$ would then be the free product of $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ and the other fundamental group.

As far as $\pi_{1}(X/\beta)$ goes, I would hazard to guess that we could then contract the circle on the first picture with the $\beta$ identification, and that $\pi_{1}(X/\beta) \cong \mathbb{Z_{2}}$ then. Is this true? It sounds too easy to be true, but that's the only reasoning that I could think of.

As far as the retract questions go, I have made no progress in answering them. I would appreciate any assistance with this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's the Mobius strip? Seems to me like it's the projective plane. It looks like the fundamental group of $X$ is actually $C_2\ast C_3$.

Comment: @Steve D :oh, absolutely, it's the real projective plane, $N_{1} \approx \mathbb{R}P^{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain how you got $C_{3}$, please?

Comment: Is it because it doesn't matter whether the cirlce with the $\beta$-identification in the sphere is circle-shaped or disc-shaped? Is all that matters when you have a sphere and an identification on it, which identification it is, and not the type of closed curve the identification is being done on?

Comment: Here is how I think about it: the fundamental group is determined by the two skeleton: the 1-skeleton gives you the generators, and the 2-cells give you the relations. So if you have a circle as your 1-skeleton, then your fundamental group is cyclic. If you attach one, or two, or a bunch of disks to this circle with degree $n$ maps, then the fundamental group is cyclic of order $n$.